# JQuery/JavaScript hide one clicked element but not others

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, hide

I'm creating a JavaScript and JQuery "Whack-a-Mole" game, and I'm appending "mole" images at random coordinates into the gamespace every two seconds. When a mole is clicked, I would like it to hide (disappear from the screen). However, the way I have the code written now, clicking on one mole causes all mole images to be hidden. Would love to hear any thoughts on selecting and hiding only the clicked mole image, but not hiding the other mole images.

Here's my "addMole" function:

```
function addMole() {
    xPos = randPosX();
    yPos = randPosY();
    $('#gamespace').append('<img src="img/mole.png" style="top:'+yPos+'px;left:'+xPos+'px" />').addClass('mole'); // insert mole into #gamespace
    repeatAddMole = setTimeout("addMole()", 2000); // append moles every 2 seconds
};
```

And here's the game's main function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#start_button').click(function() { 
        start();
        $('#timer').show(); // show timer
        $('.mole').on("click", function(){
            incScore();
            $('img', this).hide();
        });
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why the mole click event is defined inside the start button click event. It seems to me that you can keep them separate. Because the moles are dynamically created, you can change the jquery statement to:

$("#gamespace").on("click", ".mole", function () {
   ....
}); and simply use $(this).hide() instead of $('img', this).hide()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the `mole` class to the #gamespace, not the image. Maybe you want this:

```
$('#gamespace').append($('<img src="img/mole.png" style="top:'+yPos+'px;left:'+xPos+'px" />').addClass('mole'));
```

Here's a demo to help you https://jsfiddle.net/bradlis7/ubar2Lzb/1/. I like to keep the functions doing what they say they are doing (`addMole` should not really be setting a new timer).

Comment: That was my next comment. He was appending the mole class to the wrong thing. As a result, the gamespace is getting hidden instead of just the single image. Should be hardcoding it into the <img> tag in the html getting appended.

Comment: On top of that, the selector for hide needs to change to $(this).hide()

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#gamespace').append('<img onclick="this.style.display=\'none\'" src="img/mole.png" style="top:'+yPos+'px;left:'+xPos+'px" />').addClass('mole'); // insert mole into #gamespace
```

Comment: That makes it work, but the `addClass("mole")` is still incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Also the problem is cause you attach event only to created images (moles) before you clicked on start.
You can use event [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Use this code out of start button click handler.

```
$( "#gamespace" ).on( "click", "img", function( event ) {
  incScore();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: That delegation looks pretty useful. I've never implemented it, but I could see it being useful here and even in my own code.

Comment: Yes, that works good when you have to handle events of elements which can be added dynamically, also it has better performance cause you attach only one handle instead of many.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it pretty much in this way:

```
function addMole() {
   xPos = randPosX();
   yPos = randPosY();

   var el = $('#gamespace').append('<img src="img/mole.png" style="top:'+yPos+'px;left:'+xPos+'px" />').addClass('mole'); 
   el.on("click", function(){
       $(this).remove();
       incScore();
   });
   repeatAddMole = setTimeout("addMole()", 2000); 
};
```

append function returns you jQuery object of appended element, so you can attach event directly on it after it is created. If you create events before objects are created, events will not be attached to it. This way, you create element and then attach the event.

You could do it in the way mhodges wrote in his comment, but I simply don't like this way because I believe it's not that efficient.